# Sending XML over HTTP post

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, https, http-post

I'm not sure if I'm coming at this at the correct angle or understand this correctly but currently we have a web services in which a customer requests a product price/stock over xml http post and we send a response back with the current price and stock.

Am I correct in thinking if I want this to go over https I can simply put a certificate on the service and it will work the same way.

e.g. Instead of the customer sending the http request to http://stockrequest.example.com they send it to https://stockrequest.example.com and the transaction will be encrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. That extra "S" in the URL means your connection is secure and it's much harder for anyone else to see what you're doing.  However the client making the http request will still be able to see the request and result, but no third parties.

Comment: sorry i might not of explained my question correctly, I understand the difference between the http and https is weather or not i need to send the http post any different within the code or does iis encrypt the data and decrypt

Comment: No, you don't have to do anything differently.  If you are calling from a non secure page you may need to use jsonp though.